# File Path Tracing (Help on Maneuvering Directory)

Tags: php, web, filepath

I am hitting an error while requiring a file on my **Authentication.php**. I just want to *require* **ConnectionStrings.php**.
So, inside my Authentication.php, I have this following line of code that leads me to an error saying **failed to open stream: No such file or directory...**

```
require '../../../Database/ConnectionStrings.php';
```

Can anyone please enlighten me on whether I have written the path correctly or not? Thank you in advance, guys :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Solved it. This line works.

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'../../../../Database/ConnectionStrings.php';
```